# Updating database after cell selection (JTable)

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, actionlistener

I want to update the value of the cell I've selected in `JTable`, which should reflect the database (`HSQL`) as button's listener is called upon.

```
JButton button = new JButton("VIEW AND EDIT");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int row = table.getSelectedRow();
        int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
        //(**********************)
        System.out.println(row + " : " + column);
        table.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

What piece of code should I replace with the `*`s?

PLEASE provide me with, either a sample code, or process to do the same.

My table has 4 columns with one `PK`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the table so it matches the current state of your DB, you should

- retrieve the current state from your DB on a worker thread
- create a new `TableModel` on the worker thread, and set it on the existing table on the Event Dispatch Thread OR
- update the existing table model on the Event Dispatch Thread

If you want to edit the values in the table, and push that state to your DB

- write/use a table editor
- when your `TableModel` receives the update (in the `setValueAt` method), push that state to the database on a worker thread

Relevant links:

- [Concurrency in Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- [`JTable` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)